# How to aggregate a CloudWatch SEARCH metric across only some dimensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up a CloudWatch graph using SEARCH, I've done some before, but I can't get it to work the way I want this time. My issue is that I want to include only *some* of the metric dimensions in the graph. I can search just the namespace and metric, like this:

```
SEARCH('Namespace="MyServiceName" MetricName="LatencyFromCreation"', 'Average', 300)
```

That aggregates, but that doesn't give me any dimensions. I can include *all* the dimensions this:

```
SEARCH('{MyServiceName,ResultState,ItemType,LogGroup,ServiceName,ServiceType} LatencyFromCreation', 'Average', 300)
```

That doesn't do any aggregation, it shows me every combination of dimensions. But when I try to remove some of them (as described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/search-expression-syntax.html) and shown in [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/search-expression-examples.html)) to keep only the dimensions that I'm interested in, like this:

```
SEARCH('{MyServiceName,ItemType} LatencyFromCreation', 'Average', 300)
```

I get no results, even though the docs seem to make it clear that this *should* work, am I missing something? Are the docs inaccurate?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443899/cloudwatch-does-not-aggregate-across-dimensions-for-your-custom-metrics) which is related, but the answer that mentions using SEARCH does not make it clear if they are displaying a subset of the dimensions or not.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443899/cloudwatch-does-not-aggregate-across-dimensions-for-your-custom-metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by using CloudWatch Embedded Metrics Format (EMF) as the log format emitted by my services (as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443899/cloudwatch-does-not-aggregate-across-dimensions-for-your-custom-metrics) that Ryan linked), combined with using [Metric Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) to create new metrics from the EMF logs, in addition to the ones CloudWatch creates. This allowed me to choose exactly which dimensions I wanted included in the metric by adjusting the pattern on the filter. Then I was able to use all of the normal Metric Math goodness that CloudWatch provides on this new metric.

Feels pretty hacky, but it works.